# removing items from list that exist in another list based on an ID member

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have two lists:

```
List<Post> posts
List<Post> exceptions
```

I want to remove all items in "posts" that have a PostId matching that of an item in "exceptions"

I have tried:

```
foreach (var post in posts)
{
    if (exceptions.Where(x => x.PostId == post.PostId) != null)
    {
        posts.RemoveAll(x => x.PostId == post.PostId);
    }
}
```

but I bet there is a cleaner way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: `exceptions.Where(x => x.PostId == post.PostId) != null` - this will *always* evaluate to `true`, as [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will never return `null` (just possibly an empty enumeration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the `posts` you want to keep and override the original list:

```
posts = posts.Where(p => !exceptions.Any(e => e.PostId == p.PostId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First point : Your can't remove an item of posts when you do a foreach on posts.

Your should use a for loop instead.

Second point : use a map between each postid and the object post containing thid id, before looping. So your won't have to have a n^2 complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For easier example calculation, I have implemented the two list to contain integer numbers, not class objects but the logic is the same. As far as I understood from your example, you want to remove all the posts objects that are available in exceptions list.

```
    List<int> posts = new List<int>() { -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    List<int> exceptions = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    IEnumerable<int> intersection = exceptions.Intersect(posts); /* returns the numbers that are both in the two lists */

    posts.RemoveAll(p => intersection.Contains(p)); /* remove the numbers from 'posts' that are intersected (1, 2, 3 are removed) */
```

Comment: You should even be able to remove a level of indirection in the last line, as you can simply write: `post.RemoveAll(intersection.Contains);` There's no need to create an anonymous method that takes one argument, just to invoke one other method while handing over that very argument.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, I wrote it that way to be more easily understood that the variable 'p' is being looped and passed as an argument to the 'intersection' list.